# Can Ab Exercise Be Done Everyday

Tags: abdominals

I heard that ab muscles are tiny and can be exercised everyday.

Is this true, or do we need to take 1 to 2 day break in-between, just like the other muscle groups, i.e. arms, shoulders, back, chest, glutes, thighs, legs ....

By the way, I do light-weight exercises at home, the types you'd find on Pinterest, and maximum dumbbell weight is 8 lbs

Comment: You "exercise" your abs everyday standing up right, I'd look for answers that differentiate between regular use and adaptation causing.

Comment: @EricKaufman I meant exercising abs as part of an exercise routine ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but give it only a maximum of 5-10 minutes in your routine, with a short (30 sec) rest period in between. This will surely fetch results. The key to visibility of your abs is to lose as much fat as you can. Otherwise, you may build the muscle but will not clearly see it as the fat is covering the area.

Comment: I perform [standing tree yoga pose](http://www.gaiamtv.com/pose/tree-pose-vrksasana) (a minute each side) everyday to strengthen my core

Comment: If if you are into yoga. Then try a combination of other core exercises as well. This will strengthen your core effectively. Each pose may/may not  target the core entirely. It's better if you try out few other poses to build core strength and overall strength.

Comment: I find tree pose does more for my lower legs than core. Have you tried the plank?

Comment: Yes, I did. And it does do a lot more for your core and overall endurance. But doing one exercise alone won't do you much good. You need to work in all the angles possible to target certain region of the body. Try a set of different routines each day. To get to an esthetic look.

Comment: @Rikki  Yes I do plank few times a week.

Answer (score 2):

The abdominal muscles are muscles like any other.

If, for instance, you've found a routine that works great for your chest or upper back, try applying the same principles for your abs too. Progressive overloading!

And yes, like any other muscle group, your abs need restitution too! You can use the 48 hour rule-of-thumb to start with, and then just experiment from there. Try doing it several days in a row, and see if it works out. If it doesn't, then at least you'll know.